# How to get radiobutton list Rows length/Column with repeat horizontal mode

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

**My radiobutton list has 3 values when I repeat it vertical it gives rows length as 3 but when I repeat radio button list horizontal it gives rows length as 1.**

```
var radiosub = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_radiosub_' + i);

if (radiosub != null) {                                                                  
  var radiosubcount = radiosub.rows.length;
  alert(radiosubcount);  
}
```

My view page source layout

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_radiosub_3" class="spaced">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_radiosub_3_0_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$JewelleryServices$dtbindjewellery$ctl03$radiosub" value="7"><label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_radiosub_3_0_3">Yellow Gold</label></td>
               <td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_radiosub_3_1_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$JewelleryServices$dtbindjewellery$ctl03$radiosub" value="8"><label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_radiosub_3_1_3">Rhodium White Gold</label></td>
               <td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_radiosub_3_2_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$JewelleryServices$dtbindjewellery$ctl03$radiosub" value="9"><label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_radiosub_3_2_3">Rose Gold</label></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

**How can I get count as 3 when I repeat radio button horizontal**

Comment: When you say repeat horizontally, do you mean in a table, or using CSS? Do you have an example of the markup you're using?

Comment: I repeat radio button list horizontal from code side and on inspect it is showing 1 tr with 3 td. Like wise I repeat it vertical it shows 3 tr. This is making an issue. How can I count an repeat column

Comment: Could you post the markup being generated? From view source in whichever browser you're using?

Comment: @AndrewLeedham placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the horizontal radio inputs, you can use this code to find the count/ length

```
document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_radiosub_3").rows[0].cells.length;  // this will return the length of the cell from first row of the tabl. If you want to count the succeeding row column, you have to change the array index as 1,2...
```